# Variable precision float/double values

Tags: c#, serialization, protobuf-net

I have an object that I'm serializing that contains a lot of doubles and structs of doubles that I'm sending across the wire with protobuf-net.  The issue is that across the wire, I don't need all of that precision.

For instance, I have something like this where an external library is returning a double.

`double Volts = Sampler.GetValue(); //Volts is a value like 4.35(...)`

But I really only need two decimal points of precision.  Encoding this across the wire as a double takes 64 bits.  Encoding it as a string with 2 digits of decimal precision ("4.35") actually may take less space.  But then I have conversion issues to deal with on either side.

I've been poking around the v2 options, and I haven't seen such a capability.  I can see how it could save a ton of space if you could encode floating point values to a variable length of precision.

I've thought about multiplying out to an integer sending that and then converting it back on the far end, but as far as I can tell that would require me to make significant changes to my base class objects (and I'm using the merge option during deserialization).

Any ideas or clever work arounds?

btw, protobuf-net is awesome with tons of configurability.  Thanks for making such a great program.

Comment: *"Encoding this across the wire as a double takes 64 bytes."* - No it would take 64 *bits* = 8 byte

Comment: There's such thing as a "half float" if you're really concerned about space (err..bandwidth in this case).

Comment: Thanks, fixed the bits/bytes typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Carrying on the "maybe send them as `float`" discussion, you can do this pretty easily, actually; for example, if you currently have:

```
[ProtoMember(4)]
public double Value {get;set;}
```

you could change that to:

```
public double Value {get;set;} // this won't be serialized directly

[Protomember(4)] // but we'll use this private property for the serialization
private float ValueSingle {
    get { return (float)Value; }
    set { Value = value; }
}
```

and it will do the shim in the background for you. This *particular* change should be compatible with existing data too (although technically it does change the .proto schema, protobuf-net is fairly forgiving). This will take 4 bytes. Note also that IEEE754 applies, as always, so **completely unrelated to protobuf-net** there is no guarantee that any particular value (4.35, for example) can be stored *exactly*.

Another option, if you want **fixed** precision, would be to use a multiple. For example:

```
public double Value {get;set;}

[ProtoMember(4)]
public int ValueInt32 {
    get { return (int)Math.Round(100 * Value); }
    set { Value = value/100.0; }
}
```

You'd have to test to see if that is compatible with old data... that is a bigger change. Here, 4.35 will be sent as 435, which takes 2 bytes as a "varint".

Comment: I was actually just digging through the protobuf-net code to see about decorating a double with an attribute to do essentially the second idea where I can decorate a double with `FixedPrecision=2` and take care of it in the serialize/deserialize.  If that fails, I can likely edit the bandwidth hogs some like this.  I'd prefer not to, but if I hit my bandwidth limit, which I'm awfully close to I will have to come up with something.

I have no concern about old data; I can break things as necessary.  I think that this might be a nice feature in protobuf-net.

Comment: @Mike re the attribute; the problem there is that anything you change in v2 needs to be implemented **twice** - once in regular code, once in `ILGenerator`...

Comment: Yea, it might be quite the learning process :)  And/or epic fail :)

Comment: @MarcGravell - I find myself in a similar situation. Might we humbly suggest an additional `Type` parameter in `ProtoMemberAttribute`? E.g. `[ProtoMember(1, SerializedType = typeof(float)]`?

Answer (score 2):

Serializing your data as strings sounds like a bad idea.

Double values already are only 64 bit each (see [Protocol Buffers encoding](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/encoding.html), wire type 1), text is transferred as UTF-8 so even in your simplified example of 4.35 you need 32 bit to transfer, not to mention the effort of transforming it back to a double when you deserialize and the general maintenance nightmare when someone is looking at that code.

If you do not need the precision I would suggest using floats instead which only use 32 bits, but stay consistent in usage of these values and their serialization.

Comment: Yea, I was thinking ASCII text.  Unicode would obviously be worse.

I could use floats and halve my data size. I could just cast everywhere since everything returns doubles (including 3rd party objects).  Changing that and casting everywhere probably would touch over a thousand lines of code.

Comment: Yea, I really did screw up bits/bytes.  Too long staring at a screen.  My general problem remains though.  Floats probably aren't worth the effort with how many lines I would have to change.